# Leaflet: removeLayer by id do not work

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to remove element from map:
Work code:

```
var x = L.imageOverlay(fullURL, xbounds).addTo(Window.map);
Window.map.removeLayer(x);
```

Do not work:

```
var x = L.imageOverlay(fullURL, xbounds).addTo(Window.map);
Window.map.removeLayer(1);
```

By the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-removelayer) it have method for removing elements by IDs

Comment: The docs say that `id` should be `string`. Does it work with `"1"`?

Comment: @xmojmr no do not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, [`map.removeLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-removelayer) accepts only a layer (as in your first code).

It is [`layerGroup.removeLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-removelayer) that can also accept an ID.

This "ID" is automatically defined by Leaflet, and you can retrieve it using [`L.stamp(layer)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#util-stamp).

```js
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)
var x = L.marker(coordinates).addTo(layerGroup);
var x_id = L.stamp(x); // Retrieve the x layer ID
layerGroup.removeLayer(x_id);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/65/